# In Angular JS, How to access custom provider's function in module.config?

Tags: angularjs

I want to access function of custom provider in config section. How to do that ?

MasterApp.js

```
var masterapp= angular.module("masterapp",[]);

masterapp.value('homeurl', 'workbench');   // value will be dynamically generated.

masterapp.provider('masterprovider', function() {

 this.$get = function(homeurl) {

     return {
         makeurl: function(userFileLoc) {
              return homeurl+userFileLoc;
         }
     }
 }; 
});
```

userapp.js

// Below approach through error. How to achieve this ?

```
    var userApp= angular.module('userApp',[
        'ngRoute',
        'masterapp'
    ]);

    userApp.config(['$routeProvider', 'masterprovider'
      function($routeProvider, masterprovider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: masterprovider.makeurl('something.html'),
            controller: 'myCtrl'
          }).

       otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });
      }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access to the Factory method. Try this:

```
 masterapp.provider('masterprovider', function() {

    var homeurl = "workbench";

    this.makeurl = function(userFileLoc) {
        return homeurl + userFileLoc;
    };

    this.$get = function() {
        return {
            otherFactoryFn: function() {}
        }
    };
});
```

From [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers):

> The Provider recipe is syntactically defined as a custom type that
>   implements a $get method. This method is a factory function just like
>   the one we use in the Factory recipe. In fact, if you define a Factory
>   recipe, an empty Provider type with the $get method set to your
>   factory function is automatically created under the hood.